# How to fetch the input value of a form in another component with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, axios, react-hooks

I have used Axios with Reach Hooks. Is there any way to fetch the updated input value from form.js file so that I can use it to update the axios.get link in ApiData.js file? When the user types a value, I want to fetch that value and use in the ApiData.js file so that the value can be updated in axios.get. I have tried a lot of ways to do that by passing the **updatedInputVal** in the form.js file to a function and then trying to access it in the ApiData.js file. Nothing worked. I'm a beginner. So please let me know if you are unclear about the issue. Thanks in advance

This is the form.js file

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function UseForm(){
    const[inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({
        search: "",
        contactName:"",
        contact:""
    })

    function handleChange(e){
        const {name, value} = e.target;
        setInputValue(previousValue=>{
            if(name === "search"){
                return{
                    search: value,
                    contactName:previousValue.contactName,
                    contact:previousValue.contact   
                }
            }
        })
    }

    function onFormSubmit(event){
        let updatedInputVal = setInputValue(inputValue.search)
        event.preventDefault();
        return updatedInputVal;//Want to fetch this value and use it in the ApiData.js component
    }



    return ( 
        <div className="form-container">
            <div className="input-div">
                <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
                    <input className="form-input" onChange={handleChange} type="text" name="search" value={inputValue.search} placeholder="Search TV Shows"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className="btn-div">
                <button type="submit" className="btn">Submit</button>    
            </div>
        </div>)
}



export default UseForm;
```

This is the ApiData.js file

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
    

const FetchApiData = () =>{
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
        async function fetchData(){
        const resquest =  await axios.get(`http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${//want to insert here the updated input value the user types}`)
        const appData =  resquest.data[0].show.image.medium;
        setData(appData)
        return appData
    }  fetchData()
    }, [])
    
    return (
            <div className="section-image">
                <img src={data} alt=""/>
            </div>
            ) 
}

export default FetchApiData
```

App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import Nav from "./Nav";
import UseForm from "./Form"
import FetchApiData from './ApiData'


function App(){
    return (
    <div>
        <Nav 
        src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/logo.png`}
        title = "CONTACT US"
        />
        <UseForm/>
        <FetchApiData/>
    </div>)
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `App` component is the parent of both `FetchApiData` and `UseForm` you can simply just handle the state of this value using the `App` component and pass this property to both children.

`App` component:

```js
function App(){

    // declare state object here
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({
        search: "",
        contactName:"",
        contact:""
    });

    return (
    <div>
        <Nav 
        src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/logo.png`}
        title = "CONTACT US"
        />
        {/* Pass props to each component */}
        <UseForm inputValue={inputValue} setInputValue={setInputValue}/>
        <FetchApiData inputValue={inputValue}/>
    </div>)
}
```

`UseForm` component:

```js
function UseForm({inputValue, setInputValue}){
    // Remove this
    // const[inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({
    //     search: "",
    //     contactName:"",
    //     contact:""
    // })

    // keep everything else the same
}
```

`FetchApiData` component:

```js
const FetchApiData = ({inputValue}) =>{
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
        async function fetchData(){
        const resquest =  await axios.get(`http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${inputValue}`)
        const appData =  resquest.data[0].show.image.medium;
        setData(appData)
        return appData
    }  fetchData()
    }, [inputValue])
    
    return (
            <div className="section-image">
                <img src={data} alt=""/>
            </div>
            ) 
}
```

`FetchApiData` will re-render every time `inputValue` changes. Just take note of that unless it is the intended behaviour.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it 

Answer (score 1):

You need to *lift* the `inputValue` state to `App` component and pass it via `props`:

```
function App(){
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({
        search: "",
        contactName:"",
        contact:""
    })
    return (
    <div>
        <Nav 
        src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/logo.png`}
        title = "CONTACT US"
        />
        <UseForm inputValue={inputValue} setInputValue={setInputValue}/>
        <FetchApiData inputValue={inputValue}/>
    </div>)
}

function UseForm({inputValue, setInputValue}){
 // ...
}
```

Also, a state-management solution like `Redux` can also help in managing state separately from component so that you don't need to pass state via props like shown above.